# Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

this is the scenario, I have this form
HTML

```
<form class="mainForm" name="eform" id="eform" action="/itg/sc_cust_maint_pkg.cust_dml"         method="get">
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
<div class="rowElem noborder"><label>Customer ID:</label>
<div class="formRight240">
<input type="text" name="p_cust_id_c" id="req" class="validate[required,maxSize[30]]"/>
</div></span><div class="fix"></div>
```

What I have to do is validate the required input, and add asterisk to the label,the working mode is to fix the problems using what we have, so I have to find a solution using just this. the million question is, how to validate if p_cust_id_c is required using that class, and once do that then add an asterisk to the label.

Comment: sorry for the disorganization I am having a hard time with the editor

Comment: Which libraries are used? Or is the class name of `#req` as complex as it is just for your own script?

Comment: There's a closing span in the middle of that code, but no opening span, and it's missing several closings ?

Comment: suggest to use jQuery validation plugin for this

Comment: yes I post just a piece of the code, I want to show you the form and one field example, the complete code is too big, is using the library validation of jquery, I have to do javascript solution ignore the span, the span is the actual asterisk in the input field but i have to do it dinamyc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the elements, check if the inputs class contains the string `required`, then add something to the label ?

```
var form  = document.getElementById('eform');
var input = document.getElementById('req');
var label = form.getElementsByTagName('label')[0];

if (input.className.indexOf('required') != -1) {
    label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML + '***';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mfNG6/)

Comment: can I get the elements by type, lets say get all the inputs and then validate if string required is place?

Comment: because the way i know if the field or element is required is just by the required param inside the jquery

Comment: you guys have too much experience for this, :( i am just a beginner, well I guess that is how you start, thanks a lot men, and this will say ? if this element have the required then go to the previous label and add the asterisk right?

Comment: Yes, it loops over the inputs, checking for the string in the classname, and based on that markup it finds the label and adds asterix etc ?